# Xamarin get the native control in custom renderer

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have two custom views (HybridEntry and HybridSlider) with custom renderers for each platform. In the custom renderers, HybridSlider has to use some of the platform-specific functionalities of HybridEntry.

In short, I want to access the native control of HybridEntry inside the custom renderers of HybridSlider.

I could pass the reference of the Forms HybridEntry to the Forms HybridSlider class in the xaml by declaring a property named HybridEntry inside of HybridSlider class.

**XAML:**

```
<local:HybridEntry x:Name="hybridEntry"></local:HybridEntry>
<local:HybridSlider HybridEntry="{x:Reference hybridEntry}"></local:HybridSlider>
```

Custom renderer of HybridSlider in UWP -

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(handler: typeof(Core.CustomView.HybridSlider), target: typeof(Demo.UWP.Renderers.HybridSliderwRenderer))]
namespace Demo.UWP.Renderers
{
    public class HybridSliderwRenderer : ViewRenderer<Core.CustomView.HybridSlider, UserControl>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Core.CustomView.HybridSlider> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var formsHybridEntry = e.NewElement.HybridEntry;

                Demo.UWP.HybridEntry uwpEntry= (Demo.UWP.HybridEntry)formsHybridEntry; // I WANT TO GET THE NATIVE control here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I access the native control class which is associated with the HybridEntry class inside of custom renderer of HybridSlider?

Comment: does `this.Element` not work?

Answer (score 1):

This blog post focuses on getting the Native Control of a Shared Control.

http://michaelridland.com/xamarin/creating-native-view-xamarin-forms-viewpage/

For UWP it might be very similiar, definitel look into the `RendererFactory.GetRenderer (view)` method. But it could be outdated already. If so, you will find up-to-date approaches on the web.